# Bug in Spring Boot 3.0.3 with EnableWebSocketMessageBroker

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I was testing the example for spring websockets (https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) and found a problem in version 3.0.3 in Spring Boot. With version 3.0.2 everything works as expected. But with 3.0.3 i get a 404 error when trying to connect via /gs-guide-websocket/info. Did someone has the same problem or know a bug in this version?

```
2023-02-27T12:44:14.955+01:00 DEBUG 17724 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   ...

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#formContentFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.formcontent.filter.enabled) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration#flashMapManager matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: flashMapManager; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration#localeResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: localeResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.EnableWebMvcConfiguration#themeResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: themeResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.ResourceChainCustomizerConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnEnabledResourceChain found class org.webjars.WebJarAssetLocator (OnEnabledResourceChainCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#requestContextFilter matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener,org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#viewResolver matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found beans 'defaultViewResolver', 'beanNameViewResolver', 'mvcViewResolver'; @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: viewResolver types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'jakarta.servlet.Servlet', 'jakarta.websocket.server.ServerContainer' (OnClassCondition)
      - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.TomcatWebSocketConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat', 'org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.TomcatWebSocketConfiguration#websocketServletWebServerCustomizer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: websocketServletWebServerCustomizer; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   ...

   WebClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' (OnClassCondition)

   WebFluxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#hiddenHttpMethodFilter:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.hiddenmethod.filter.enabled) did not find property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.ProblemDetailsErrorHandlingConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.mvc.problemdetails.enabled=true) did not find property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#beanNameViewResolver:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver' beanNameViewResolver (OnBeanCondition)

   WebServiceTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller' (OnClassCondition)

   WebServicesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSessionIdResolverAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Mono' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration.WebSocketMessageConverterConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration,com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper', 'org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketReactiveAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnWebApplication did not find reactive web application classes (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.JettyWebSocketConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jakarta.server.config.JakartaWebSocketServletContainerInitializer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration.UndertowWebSocketConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.undertow.websockets.jsr.Bootstrap' (OnClassCondition)

   XADataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'jakarta.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.LifecycleAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.availability.ApplicationAvailabilityAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: can you turn on spring debug logs (org.springframework.* set to DEBUG) and add the webserver logs here?

Comment: I can't understand why 'WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration.WebSocketMessageConverterConfiguration' did not find the 'DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration'-Bean. In my Configuration-Class i added the EnableWebSocketMessageBroker-Annotation which imports DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration.class

Comment: If you're running your application on Windows and it has a space in its path, this could be caused by https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30031.

Comment: I really think it is a timing- or order-error on conditions. Just switching from boot 3.0.3 back to 3.0.2 fixed the error. The condition on bean 'DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration' then is true and everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it with the new Spring Boot version 3.0.4 and there everything works well again. I think they have fixed something in this version.